# Pipes and Cisterns : Two Filling Pipes

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> A cistern of $475$ liters is completely filled using pipes $A$ and
> $B$, with Pipe $A$ being open for $5$ more hours than pipe $B$. If we
> are to interchange the operating hours of the two pipes than pipe $A$
> would have pumped half the water as much as pipe $B$, then find the
> time for which pipe $B$ was open. Also, given that if the two pipes
> were open simultaneously the tank would fill in $19$ hours.

My solution approach :- 
Let the flow of $A$ be $x \text{ liters/hour}$ an the flow of $B$ be $y \text{ liters/hour}$.

As per the question;
$19x+19y=475$
$\Rightarrow x+y = 25$

From here we can say that the flow of $A$ be $25-y \text{ liters/hour}$ an the flow of $B$ be $y \text{ liters/hour}$.

For the first scenario with Pipe $A$ being open for $5$ more hours than pipe $B$ :-
Let $A$ be open for $t+5$ hours then $B$ will be open for $t$ hours. Then;
$(25-y)(t+5)+yt=475$
$\Rightarrow 5t-y=70$
$\Rightarrow y=5t-70$

For the second scenario when we are to interchange the operating hours of the two pipes then ;
$A$ will be open for $t$ hours then $B$ will be open for $t+5$ hours. Now as per question :- 
$(25-y)t = 0.5y(t+5)$
$\Rightarrow \text{Putting the value of $y=5t-70$ and simplifying the equation we will get }3t^2-5t-112=0$
$\Rightarrow t=7$
and this is not the correct answer that has been provided for this problem. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Please help !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic equation you obtained after simplifying is incorrect. You get:
$$2t(95-5t)=(5t-70)(t+5)$$
This simplifies to:
$$3t^2-47t-70=0$$
Which has roots: $t=\frac {47 \pm {\sqrt {3049}}}{6}$

Only one of these roots is positive, $t\approx 17$.